# Input/character validation on an input-element

Tags: javascript

I took some time to create a function, which can validate which keys you input on an element. So far it has two uses:

1. You call `.validate()` on the object, but make sure it has a `data-match` attribute with the regex in it
2. You call `.validate("REGEX")` on the object, but replace `REGEX` with your actual regular expression

Here is an example:

```
document.getElementById("input").validate("[0-9A-Fa-f]");
```

This will *only* allow characters 0-9, A-F, and a-f. Nothing else.

I want to know, if I can improve this code. So far I have it the way I want it to be, but I would surely love someone else's feedback on it as well. It is really light-weight and can easily be implemented.

Thanks a lot!

```js
Object.prototype.validate = function(myRegex) {
    var regex = this.getAttribute("data-match") || myRegex;
    var allowed = [8, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46];
    this.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        var c = (e.metaKey ? '⌘-' : '') + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
        if (!e.shiftKey && !e.metaKey) c = c.toLowerCase();
        if ((e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode == 65 || e.keyCode == 97)) || c == '⌘-A') return true;
        if (c.match(regex) || allowed.indexOf(e.which) >= 0) {
            //Do nothing
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}

document.getElementById("input").validate("[0-9A-Fa-f]");
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Whatever you do DON'T MODIFY `Object.prototype`

Modifying `Object.prototype` is one of the worst things you can do in JavaScript

Quoting [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto):

> **Warning**: Changing the `[[Prototype]]` of an object is, by the nature of how modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, a very slow operation, in ***every***    browser and JavaScript engine. The effects on performance of altering inheritance are subtle and far-flung, and are not limited to simply the time spent in `obj.__proto__ = ... statement`, but may extend to ***any*** code that has access to ***any*** object whose `[[Prototype]]` has been altered. If you care about performance you should avoid setting the `[[Prototype]]` of an object. Instead, create a new object with the desired `[[Prototype]]` using `Object.create()`.

---

#### What should I do?

Preferably create a function:

```
function Validate(element, regex) {
    // code
}
```

but if you want to extend an element use `Element.prototype`, preferable with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'validate', {
    value: function(regex) {
        // code
    }
});
```

The bonus of using this is you can instead of getters and setters which are pretty cool too.

## Avoid empty `ifs`

Here you have:

```
if (c.match(regex) || allowed.indexOf(e.which) >= 0) {
    //Do nothing
} else {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

instead, use a NOT (`!`):

```
if (!(c.match(regex) || allowed.indexOf(e.which) >= 0))
    e.preventDefault();
```

the best way to write this specific condition would be:

```
if(!c.match(regex) || allowed.indexOf(e.which) < 0)
```

## Use clear variable names

As much as I love code-golf (writing short code), this is not it. Make sure your variable names are clear.

I don't know what the `c` variable does so I can't suggest an alternative name, this also makes it more confusing to me on the workings of your code.

## Use Regex literals not strings

Your example shows:

```
"[0-9A-Fa-f]"
```

That's a string, not a Regex, use Regex literals (to avoid escaping also):

```
/[0-9A-Fa-f]/
```

Comment: Good answer overall. For the point about clear variable names, I think that the variable `e` is just fine; I find that it's quite common in JavaScript for `e` to be used as a parameter, especially when the method is an event listener.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! First of: This is going to be used on an element, which is why I modified `Object.prototype`. That seems to be the only way, I can create a `.validate()` function. Second of: The empty if-statement doesn't really work for me. I was originally going to leave out the `//Do nothing` but I couldn't figure out how to actually do it. Neither could you, because it doesn't work. Third of: Okay, I'll name my `c` variable `char`, even though `c` is a common abbreviation for character. Fourth.. of?: Yes this would work better, even though it's just a set of characters.

Comment: Oh and also, the empty if would generally be used for a "Hey you entered an invalid character"-tooltip, so it won't just ignore them.

Comment: @Downgoat Concerning the usage of ifs: Isn't it harder to think the way (NOT someState === true) ? I'm not sure ... but (someState === true) feels more natural to me. Might be a personal preference ... What's the exact benefit of write it the suggested way?

Answer (score 2):

### Change.. all the objects!

No, don't do that. Downgoat already explains why. This will touch *every object*. I shouldn't be able to do this:

```
var foo = {
    bar: "hello world"
};

foo.validate(...);
```

Instead, if you want to modify prototypes, you should modify the prototype of [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement). This will only touch input elements now, but you should still do some validation that the element is of type `text`.

```
HTMLInputElement.prototype.validate = function() {
    ...
}
```

---

### Built-in `pattern`

Now, I don't know if you already know about this, but `input` tags already have a feature for validating input: [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).

With pattern, you simply specify a regex and the form cannot be submitted unless that criteria is met. Now, this isn't exactly what you have: you have it so the user cannot even enter a wrong character. I personally don't think this makes a difference; after-all, most every input field should exist in some sort of form.

Here's an example usage:

```
<input type="text" pattern="([0-9]){3}"/>
```

Another good reason for using the built-in `pattern` would be that you won't have to do any extra meta key validation when the user is typing, in case you aren't handling all the possible cases. `pattern` is much more flexible.

Comment: Do note that [pattern support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern) isn't _perfect_ on iOS / Mac (though it's still pretty good on modern browsers)

Comment: Well, at least on Safari for iOS / Mac. But who uses Safari? (besides Alex)

Comment: 1) I COULD do `HTMLInputElement` but I wanted it to be as "versatile" as possible. So I want it to work on `<textarea>` elements as well, for instance. 2) Yes, I know about pattern, but it doesn't work for this type of application unfortunately. You can still enter a wrong character, but it will give you an error message when you defocus the element. Mine simply takes a set of characters, then validates if the entered character is legal. Something you cannot do with the new HTML5 attributes.